# Echoing dynamic route name in URL::route() while looping

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, echo, laravel-blade

I have an array in which each Section holds information about its **status** and **route** name:

```
$sections = array(
    'Section_1' => array(
        'status' => 1,
        'route' => 'section1.route'
        ),
    'Section_2' => array(
        'status' => 0,
        'route' => 'section2.route'
        ),
    'Section_3' => array(
        'status' => 1,
        'route' => 'section3.route'
        )
    );
```

I'm trying to loop through it to create a HTML list.

**I tried this (1):**

```
@foreach ($sections as $dataName => $details)
    <li>
        <a href="{{ URL::route($details['route']) }}">{{ $dataName }}</a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

**This (2):**

```
@foreach ($sections as $dataName => $details)
    <li>
        <?php $routeName = $details['route']; ?>
        <a href="{{ URL::route($routeName) }}">{{{ $dataName }}}</a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

**And this (3):**

```
@foreach ($sections as $dataName => $details)
    <li>
        <?php $routeName = URL::route($details['route']); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $routeName; ?>">{{{ $dataName }}}</a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

All of the above throw the same error:

**Route [] not defined.**

**InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined.")**

All the routes in the array exist - checked them for typos and so on. I have a feeling this might be something tiny but I don't see what. Any ideas?

PS. I'm aware I can store full routes in the array, like `'route' => URL::route('section1.route')` etc. But what is wrong with the pieces of code above?

**EDIT: Sample route**

```
Route::get('user/show/section1',
    array(
        'before' => 'auth',
        'uses' => 'UserController@showSection1',
        'as' => 'section1.route'
        )
    );
```

I'm using named routes.

Comment: can you add your routes too?

Comment: So in your routes you have something like Route::get('user/profile', array('as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'));

Comment: How you pass the data to your blade from your controller ? thats foreach is inside blade file right? its mean your view?

Comment: @Nucleo1985 `$data['sections'] = $sections` and then `return View::make('user.section1', $data)`

Comment: `return View::make('hello')->with('sections', $sections);` try this

Comment: @Nucleo1985 Tried that. Same error.

Comment: @lesssugar ah i see, hold on im testing it now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after simple test, i create simulation code like below.

On my routes i set this:

```
Route::get('user/show/section1',
    array(
        'before' => 'auth',
        'uses'   => 'HomeController@showWelcome',
        'as'     => 'section1.route'
    )
);

Route::get('user/show/section2',
    array(
        'before' => 'auth',
        'uses'   => 'HomeController@s2',
        'as'     => 'section2.route'
    )
);
Route::get('user/show/section3',
    array(
        'before' => 'auth',
        'uses'   => 'HomeController@s2',
        'as'     => 'section3.route'
    )
);
```

And simulated method on my controller:

```
public function showWelcome()
    {
        $sections = array(
            'Section_1' => array(
                'status' => 1,
                'route' => 'section1.route'
            ),
            'Section_2' => array(
                'status' => 0,
                'route' => 'section2.route'
            ),
            'Section_3' => array(
                'status' => 1,
                'route' => 'section3.route'
            )
        );

        return View::make('hello')->with('sections', $sections);
    }

    public function s2()
    {

    }

    public function s3()
    {

    }
```

Then loop it on view using your first method

```
@foreach($sections as $dataName => $details)
    <li>
        <a href="{{ URL::route($details['route']) }}">{{ $dataName }}</a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

And yes, i got the result as a html link:

```
 <li>
    <a href="http://exam.com/public/user/show/section1">Section_1</a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a href="http://exam.com/public/user/show/section2">Section_2</a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a href="http://exam.com/public/user/show/section2">Section_3</a>
 </li>
```

[image: Page source screenshot]

So check your routes.php, check if another routes taking your controller method. Its between your routes and your controller. The array has passed to view in correct way. Nothing to do with it.

Comment: The array is correclty passed to my view. The problem is with `echo`ing the `$details['route']` in the `<a href="{{ URL::route() }}"`.

Comment: I see, hold on im testing it here.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason this should not work, unless `$sections` is not being passed to the view, or the route names are not matching what you've assigned in your routes file.

```
@foreach ($sections as $dataName => $details)
    <li>
        <a href="{{ route($details['route']) }}">{{ $dataName }}</a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Unless you are using Laravel 5 (which isn't released yet)?

If so, then you might need to use the new blade syntax: `{!! route($details['route']) !!}`